# Is this a good description for potential energy?

Tags: forces, work, potential, potential-energy, definition

The potential energy can be seen as the energy stored in a system that can be "expelled". An object at a height $h$ above its reference point has a potential energy given by $U_{gravitational} = mgh$.
This means that it has the potential to release energy by going to a state of lower potential energy. 
For the object to be at height $h$ it must've had a force act on it to elevate it to a state of higher potential. The definition of work is
$$W = \int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$$ 
which translates the amount of work necessary to aply a force over a path C.
If I do work to elevate a certain object to height $h$ then the work I've done is, by definition $$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s} = \int_0^h \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_0^h F \,dy = Fh$$
This force $F$ is opposite in direction but the same in magnitude to the gravitational force, which is $\vec{F_g} = -mg\hat{y}$ if you're close enough to the Earth, $\hat{y}$ being the unit vector with upwards direction.
So, we arrive at the conclusion that the work I did to elevate the object is $W = mgh$. 
This work, done by me, is the current potential energy of the object, if we take our initial point as the point of reference, where the potential is zero, which is what we expected in the first place. I do work to elevate an object and increase its potential energy by the same amount of work I did.
But since the force I had to apply on the object was opposite to the force applied on it by gravity then the work done by gravity, to get the object to its higher level of potential energy is also opposite to the work done by me, right?
This work, done by gravity, is then $W = -mgh$. Thus we can also define the potential energy (in the case of gravity) as
$$U = \int_{ref}^P \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s} = -\int_{ref}^P \vec{F_g}\cdot d\vec{s}$$
where $ref$ is the point, taken as reference, where the potential is zero.
Bottom line is: 
Gravitational potential energy seems to be the energy you expend to elevate an object a certain distance, by which you have to overcome the **force it's subjected to**. In other words, gravitational potential energy is the work you do **against** (thus the minus sign) the force of gravity to lift the object.

In the case of the electrostatic potential energy, the same thing seems to occur.
$$U_{electrostatic} = -\int_{ref}^P \vec{F_{el}} \cdot d\vec{s}$$
So my question is, because you're probably tired of reading all this nonsense, is the potential energy simply the work you have to do to move an object to a certain place? Whereby you have to overcome the force it's subjected to?
Is that minus sign always going to be there **because** you're overcoming that force? Is that why it's there?
I've been stuck with this question for days now because when I think I've made sense of it I realize that things aren't always that simple. So, putting it simply, is my understanding of it correct?

I'm open to any corrections, any criticism, anything. Just point out what is wrong so I can do more thinking on it.

Answer (score 0):

> is the potential energy simply the work you have to do to move an object to a certain place?

**Yes**. Or more precisely, the potential energy **equals** the work you do.

But that's just a detail in the wording.

> Whereby you have to overcome the force it's subjected to? Is that minus sign always going to be there because you're overcoming that force? Is that why it's there?

**Yes**. There *must* be the minus sign. Because there *must* be a force working **against** you, while you move the object. If there *wasn't* a force working against that movement, you couldn't end up storing the energy as potential energy in the end.

Potential energy exists because there is a force, trying to move something somewhere. Storing potential energy means by definition that you are moving something *against* this force, so that the force can now pull that thing back again. The *"against"* is the minus sign.

> I've been stuck with this question for days now because when I think I've made sense of it I realize that things aren't always that simple. So, putting it simply, is my understanding of it correct?

Well, I must admit that this question is one of the most well-formulated and accurate questions I've seen for a long time. Everything you write is correct. I do not see the actual definition, which your title refers to, but nevertheless, the entire description is correct.

Comment: Well I guess by definition I meant more like "description" haha. Thanks for your answer, it really puts my mind at ease. These topics in school are very often explained by telling you "how to do it" rather then "why this is the way you do it". And then, when you have to deal with a situation where what is necessary is the "understanding" of it, you inevitably fail.

Comment: @Pedre Well, I can only say that if you've understood the concept of energy, you've come a looong way - it's one of the most confusing parts of physics, in my opinion.